# Как заставить работать шаблон с enable_if, который должен принимать контейнер с содержимым нужного типа?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Хочу написать шаблон, который будет принимать контейнер точек. Данная перегрузка расчитана на наличие у `Point` методов `Point::x()` и `Point::y()`:

```
template<
    typename Point,
    template<typename> typename Container,
    typename = std::enable_if_t // SFINAE
    <
           std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Point::x),Point>
        && std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Point::y),Point>

        && is_numeric_v<return_type_t<decltype(&Point::x)>>
        && is_numeric_v<return_type_t<decltype(&Point::y)>>

        && std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Container<Point>::begin),Container<Point>>
        && std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&Container<Point>::end),Container<Point>>
    >
>
double calc_intersection_percentage(Container<Point> polygon)
{ return 0.0; }
```

Вот такой код выводит только `true`:

```
std::clog << std::boolalpha                                                
          << std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&MyPoint::x),MyPoint> << std::endl 
          << std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&MyPoint::y),MyPoint> << std::endl 
          << is_numeric_v<return_type_t<decltype(&MyPoint::x)>> << std::endl 
          << is_numeric_v<return_type_t<decltype(&MyPoint::y)>> << std::endl;
```

При попытке вызова:

```
std::vector<MyPoint> polygon = {
    {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7}
};
calc_intersection_percentage(polygon);
```

Валится ошибка:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'calc_intersection_percentage'
> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure
> [with Point = MyPoint]: template template argument has different
> template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
> ```

**Не могу понять, что я делаю не так?**

Comment: Как минимум, не приводите [mcve].

Comment: или хотя бы показать, что такое return_type_t -  в стандратных поставках компиляторов я такого не нашел

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня вдруг всё заработало. Я даже пока не понял почему) `return_type_t` - это метафункция для того, чтобы достать из типа функции возвращаемый тип.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот тут не хватало Parametr Pack'а `template<typename...> typename Container`

Comment: думаю, будет хорошо привести полный пример, такой код может пригодится и другим людям

Comment: @KoVadim, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201835/get-the-type-of-the-return-value-in-c